# my style tag in my polymer web component has an include, where are the docs?

Tags: html, css, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I see someone implemented some custom style tags weirdly.

```
<dom-module id="my-style">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host{
         width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

with no dart file, and then has another file with the component.

```
<link rel="import" href="my_stylesheet.html">
<dom-module id="my-custom-element">
  <template>
    <style include="my-style"></style>
    <div>Hello World!</div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

WITH the associated Dart file to register the tag.

Is this right?  is this wrong?  I feel something is off.

When I look at this implementation I see the follow ordered operations.

1. Attempt to load `my-custom-element` in a page
2. Imports the style html into the dom under a custom tag, called: `my-style`
3. Continues to load the component.

...

now this is where it gets fuzzy for me.  `include` is not an attribute of html, so i am guessing it is polymer, but references the custom style tag.

...

99. code is injected somehow and that set of styles is applied to to the component.
100. element is no longer needed, detached / killed.
101. custom tag is still on page as it is outside the custom element.
102. custom element is created.    injecting another `my-style` tag.
103. 2 tags of same name on doc.

I dunno.  Maybe you see the issue I am seeing.  This is just weird to me.  Can this be explained as to what include is and what is going on here?  I feel it needs to be improved.

Is there a cleanup issue with these modules not being removed then, etc?

Thank you

Just noticed:  The index.html has a polymer component lite js file, so that might be why there is no register of the style module, but now im curious if that is also bad since we are mixing implementation languages?

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly valid and good practice for themeing.

See style modules https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules

Comment: Yeah, I was looking in there.  I just didnt understand why the link tags are put in placeI guess my issue of logic comes into play where items are called multiple times, or cleanup occurs..  Then that link tag is injected a few times, and conversely, isnt removed when the item is destroyed, but instead removed when the parent is destroyed, no?

Comment: I haven't investigated that closely but I assume there is a lot of complexity related to shimming and polyfilling shadow DOM and CSS variables.